# Flutter: Make iFame fullscreen on Android device

Tags: android, flutter, iframe

I'm trying to load an iFrame by using `webview_flutter`. I cann't full screen the video on Android. It works well on iOS.

Here is my set-up.
`webview_flutter: 0.3.18+1`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'IFrameTest',
    home: IFrameDemo(),
  ));
}

class IFrameDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Iframe'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            child: WebView(
          initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString(
                  '<html><body><iframe width="300" height="200"  src="http://player.youku.com/embed/XODY3NDMzNjY4" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>',
                  mimeType: 'text/html').toString(),
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I click the full-screen button on the right-bottom corner, I will get the following error:

```
2020-03-02 11:50:38.411 7845-7845/com.example.helloiframe E/InputMethodManager: b/117267690: Failed to get fallback IMM with expected displayId=1 actual IMM#displayId=0 view=io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.InputAwareWebView{4981903 VFEDHVC.. .F...... 0,0-1080,1840}
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

use [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)

here is a sample code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MaterialApp(home: new MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Sample")),
        body: SizedBox(
          height: 250,
          child: InAppWebView(
            initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(
              data: 'YOUR IFRAME'
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an open [ticket in GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27101), currently fullscreen in [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/install) is [not yet supported](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67791#issuecomment-707158902).

> I can reproduce the issue, this is not supported yet
> [#27101](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27101) Please
> follow up on that issue, I'm closing the current one as a duplicate.
> If you disagree, please write in the comments and I will reopen it.
> Thank you